# Pass data id from button to form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have a button that triggers the modal:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-subscription" data-toggle="modal" data-workspace_id="{{ workspace.id }}" data-target="#addSubscription">Add</button>
```

There is an ID value that I need.

In modal I have a form with hidden field *workspaceId* where I need to pass the value that is defined in the button that triggers that modal.

```
 <div id="addSubscription" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <form class="form" id="subscription-form" action="{{ path('my_route') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="hidden" name="workspaceId" value="">
       <input id="form-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
    </form>
  </div>
```

When I enter

```
value="15"
```

my form works as it should.

I am new with javascript functions so I have no idea how to pass **data-workspace_id** trough my method.

And this is the method:

```
$().click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#addSubscription').modal();
});

$('#form-submit').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/subscription/add',
    data: $('form#subscription-form').serialize(),
    processData: false,
    success: function () {
        console.log('Yezzz!');
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log(this.data);
    }
  });
  return false;
 });
```

Note: This is work on my Symfony project with twig view.

Comment: Could you add the JS where you open the modal. Because that's the part where you need to select the data attribute and set the value.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the post. @EmielZuurbier

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your modal gets open you can write event i.e :`show.bs.modal` then using this event get the button which has called modal using i.e `$(event.target).attr('data-workspace_id')`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//will get call when modal will be open
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#addSubscription', function (e) {
    //put the value of attr inside input box
     $("input[name=workspaceId]").val($(event.target).attr('data-workspace_id'))
  console.log($(event.target).attr('data-workspace_id'))
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-subscription" data-toggle="modal" data-workspace_id="12" data-target="#addSubscription">Add</button>

<div id="addSubscription" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <form class="form" id="subscription-form" action="{{ path('my_route') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="workspaceId" value="">
    <input id="form-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
  </form>
</div>
```

Other way using button you can get the value of `data-workspace_id` like this `$(this).attr('data-workspace_id')`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//on click of button
$(".add-subscription").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //put value in input box using this .
  $("input[name=workspaceId]").val($(this).attr('data-workspace_id'))
  $('#addSubscription').modal();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-subscription" data-toggle="modal" data-workspace_id="12" data-target="#addSubscription">Add</button>

<div id="addSubscription" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <form class="form" id="subscription-form" action="{{ path('my_route') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="workspaceId" value="">
    <input id="form-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
  </form>
</div>
```